# Trying to create a table of calculated values from and initial to final value incremented by a given number

Tags: c, for-loop, increment

This is part of a larger program but the only part I am having trouble with is generating the table of calculated values starting and ending at an initial and final value. For some reason, when the given increment value is `0.2`, it works perfectly fine, but when the value given is `0.05`, it does not display the final value.

here is the code I have for that section:

```
for (volume = initialVol; volume <= finalVol; volume += volumeIncrement) {

    pressure = pressure_cal(gasNumber, temperature, volume, gasQuantity);

    printf("%.3lf\t\t\t %.4lf\n", volume, pressure);
}
```

Also, if I change the `for` condition to `volume <= finalVol + volumeIncrement`, it will work for `0.05`, but not `0.2`.

edit: I thought I would also add that if I replace the userdef function with let's say, pressure = 1; the displayed values for volume are not affected whatsoever.

Comment: and this function?: ***pressure_cal(gasNumber, temperature, volume, gasQuantity);***

Comment: It is a function to calculate a value for pressure with the given value for volume. It is supposed to increment by volumeIncrement (0.2 or 0.05) and calculate all the possible pressure values from the initial to final volume.

Comment: maybe is that function the one that is not working....

Comment: I don't think the function is really changing any values in the for loop and it is generating all the correct values. I mean if I replace it with pressure = 1 I get the same results

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in general.  You would do best, probably, doing the arithmetic with integers and dividing by a suitable number (10.0 or 100.0, perhaps) to get the floating point value you need.

Comment: `volume <= finalVol` -> `volume <= finalVol+ volumeIncrement/2` would be a workaround for floating point precision demons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the rounding errors in floating point calculations dealing with factions that cannot be precisely represented in the `double` or `float` format.  Your increments of `0.2` or `0.05` are integral multiples of negative powers of 2, so the representation in IEEE binary format is rounded:

- If `volumeIncrement` is rounded to a lower value, the final test will succeed because `volume` will be a tiny bit smaller than `finalVol`. This is what happens for `0.2`;
- conversely, if `volumeIncrement` is rounded to a larger value, the final test will fail because `volume` will exceed `finalVol`. This is what happens for `0.05`.

There are multiple ways to avoid this problem:

- You can add a small value to `volume` to ensure the final comparison succeeds: `volume <= finalVol + volumeIncrement/2` would be a simple way to achieve this.
- You can use integer arithmetics and only convert to floating point for the calculations, not for the enumeration.  You would for example use integral numbers of milliliters instead of fractional numbers of liters and use increments of `20` or `5`.
- You can specify the number of steps instead of the increment.

Here is the modified code for the last approach:

```
int steps = 100;
for (int step = 0; step <= steps; step++) {
    double volume = initialVol + (finalVol - initialVol) * step / steps;
    double pressure = pressure_cal(gasNumber, temperature, volume, gasQuantity);
    printf("%.3f\t\t\t %.4f\n", volume, pressure);
}
```